# How do I customize an Android Explode transition?

Tags: c#, android, animation, xamarin, material-design

I am using the explode transition for an exit transition when leaving an activity:

```
var exit = new Explode();
exit.SetDuration(1000);

Window.ExitTransition = Window.EnterTransition = exit;
Window.SharedElementExitTransition = TransitionInflater.From(this).InflateTransition(
    Resource.Transition.FabTransition);

StartActivity(new Intent(
    this, typeof(ActivityMain)),
     ActivityOptions.MakeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).ToBundle());
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to really explode, the entire activity and all of its children exit the window through the top edge.  I would like it to split down the center; all views above the center of the activity should exit through the top and all views below the center should exit through the bottom.

I have tried everything from creating a custom transition that inherits the Explode class in order to override the Epicenter { get; } property to creating my own Transition.EpicenterCallback and nothing seems to work right.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hey did you find a solution to this?